# Output of python script is showing- unlimited

Tags: python

Script 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["ulimit", "-c"], shell=True)
```

Output- `unlimited`

Script 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["ulimit", "-c"], shell=True)
```

Output- `0`

I know its a basic question, please bear me and answer

Comment: Why do you have a quotation mark next to `shell=True`?

Comment: Why do you have an extra " at the end?

Comment: Script 1 is identical to Script 2. Neither will output anything due to the `"` between `True` and `)`.

Comment: What's the difference between the scripts?.. :-\

Comment: the output is different @Lev Levitsky

Comment: No way. You are not showing the actual code, the occasional syntax errors (now fixed) prove it. We can't answer your question unless you show the actual code. Make a short __working__ example and copy it precisely.

Comment: @jamylak: [`print` is not necessary. Q.E.D.](http://ideone.com/1pGoEw)

Comment: @Johnsyweb Oh right nvm that I forgot this was run from the console

Answer (score 2):

The `unlimited` and `0` are different outputs, with different meanings.

`unlimited` is the actual value of `ulimit` when you call it, and if you check the man page, `0` is the result of the call, meaning that `ulimit` executed successfully.

```
In [1]: import subprocess

In [2]: subprocess.call(["ulimit", "-c"], shell=True)
unlimited
Out[2]: 0
```

If you assign to a variable, you can see that the result is `0`, but unlimited is outputted to the standard output by the process that you're calling (and **not** returned by the call).

Comment: actually i want to execute the unix command :( ulimit -c unlimited  )
through python script. can you please tell how to do it?

Comment: @BaijnathJaiswal use `subprocess.check_output(["ulimit", "-c"], shell=True)`

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary, how to set the value as unlimited..?

Comment: Also, don't use `shell=True` when supplying a list to Popen. If `shell=True` give it a string to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [resource module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) is a lot easier, and it allows for `resource.setrlimit` which your subprocess cannot do at all as its actions would be local to the child process and would not affect the Python parent.

```
>>> import resource
>>> resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CORE)
(0L, -1L)
```

Comment: +1 for resource module, new one for me.

Comment: @ msw, Thanks, but still i did not get reply that how to set the value as unlimited..?

Comment: @BaijnathJaiswal That's because you didn't ask the question. Seeing how this one is closed, ask "How do I change the rlimit from inside a Python script" and I will happily answer. It would be better if you showed that you read the resource module page and show your effort, even if it doesn't work. We're happy to help here, but we don't write your code for you.

Comment: @msw Thanks. Sorry if you felt bad, but i have gone through resource module page, but could not find the answer. :(

Answer (score 1):

The script are identical. The problem probably is that when you just call

```
subprocess.call(["ulimit", "-c"], shell=True)
```

you get 2 outputs. The first is `unlimited` and the second one is `0`.

Try assigning the output to a variable:

```
output = subprocess.call(["ulimit", "-c"], shell=True)
```